# Is this proof by induction correct?

Tags: proof-writing

Prove by induction that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $3\mid n^3+3n^2+2n$.

$$P(1) = (1)^3+3(1)^2+2(1) = 6$$

Which is clearly divisble by $3$. Therefore, $P(1)$ is true.

Assume $P(1),\ldots,P(n)$ and show $P(n+1)$ is true.

$$(n+1)^3+ 3(n+1)^2+ 2(n+1) = n^3+6n^2+11n+6$$

This can be rewritten: $(n^3+3n^2+2n)+3(n^2+3n+2)$.

First term is divisible by $3$ because $P(n)$ is true.
The second term is divisible by $3$ because it is a multiple of $3$.
Thus, their sum is divisible by $3$.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Looks good. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @CharlesNosbig : Your MathJax code style is atrocious.  Please look at my edits.

Comment: I can see your corrections, but I don't quite understand why it is necessary. I am reasonably new here so I likely just haven't realized the importance just yet. What I did and what you corrected appear exactly the same, why does it matter if the MathJax looks a little different?

Comment: Your proof is good, but I would suggest not writing $P(1) = (1)^3+3(1)^2+2(1) = 6$, because $P(1)$ is a proposition, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks solid, but I might suggest an easier proof:

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \equiv 0, 1, 2 \pmod{3}$.  If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, we are done.

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then we have $n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n \equiv (1+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then we have $n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n \equiv (2 + 1) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

We conclude that $3|(n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n)$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: Ah, I just saw in the OP that induction was *required*.  Oh well.  Hopefully this will at least help future viewers.

Comment: I'd enjoyed the alternative regardless!